# GDAL SetProjection is not Retrieved after assigning WGS84

Tags: projection, gdal, wgs84

I got this code to set Geographic Projection to a GeoTiff File.

```
poDataset = (GDALDataset *) GDALOpen( fileName.c_str(), GA_Update);

OGRSpatialReference oSRS;
char *pszSRS_WKT = NULL;

oSRS.SetWellKnownGeogCS( "WGS84" );
oSRS.exportToWkt( &pszSRS_WKT );
oSRS.SetProjCS( pszSRS_WKT );

std::cout<<"Setted Proj: "<<pszSRS_WKT<<endl;
CPLErr err = poDataset->SetProjection( pszSRS_WKT );
std::cout<<"Proj Error: "<<err<<endl;

double        adfGeoTransform[6];
CPLErr err2 = poDataset->GetGeoTransform( adfGeoTransform );
std::cout<<"Error: "<<err2<<endl;

std::string str = poDataset->GetProjectionRef();
std::cout<<"Retrieved Proj: "<<str<<endl;
```

Result is

```
Proj: GEOGCS["WGS 84",DATUM["WGS_1984",SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,A
UTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],TOWGS84[0,0,0,0,0,0,0],AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],PRIMEM
["Greenwich",0,AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,AUTHOR
ITY["EPSG","9108"]],AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]]**

Proj Error: 0

Error: 3

Retrieved Proj:
```

Code seems reasonable, what might be the reason of this error?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

Well I solved the problem, when you set the projection, you should have assign new GeoTransformation too.
calling

```
poDataset->SetGeoTransform(adfGeoTransform);
```

solved my problem.